# How to print row of found string?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to find several strings within Word document and for each string found, I like to print (debug.print for example) the whole row content where the string is found, not the paragraph.

How can I do this? Thanks

```
Sub FindStrings
Dim StringsArr (1 to 3)

StringsArr = Array("string1","string2","string3")

For i=1 to 3
 With         
 Selection.Find 
 .ClearFormatting 
 .Text = Strings(i)  
 Debug.Print CurrentRow 'here I need help
 End With 
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ```With``` needs an object so that should be a syntax error, unless that's just a weird copy error from your code to SO and the ```selection.find``` is supposed to be on that line. Also find needs a ```.execute``` to work.

Comment: Rows in Word are only an object in tables, not in text. Just changing the font will change where the found string is located. The only way to do this would be to go through the paragraph character-by-character, getting the Selection.Information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation on each character to find the characters with the lowest Left position and highest Left position. Those characters will be the ends of the "row". Then set a range to those 2 characters to get all the text in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `Row` in Word is used only in the context of a table. I assume the term you mean is `Line`, as in a line of text.

The Word object model has no concept of "line" (or "page") due to the dynamic layout algorithm: anything the user does, even changing the printer, could change where a line or a page breaks over. Since these things are dynamic, there's no object.

The only context where "line" can be used is in connection with a `Selection`. For example, it's possible to extend a `Selection` to the start and/or end of a line. Incorporating this into the code in the question it would look something like:

```
Sub FindStrings()
  Dim StringsArr As Variant
  Dim bFound As Boolean
  Dim rng As Word.Range

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
  StringsArr = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")

  For i = LBound(StringsArr) To UBound(StringsArr)
     With rng.Find
       .ClearFormatting
       .Text = StringsArr(i)
       .Wrap = wdFindStop
       bFound = .Execute
       'extend the selection to the start and end of the current line
        Do While bFound
         rng.Select
         Selection.MoveStart wdLine, -1
         Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, 1
         Debug.Print Selection.Text
         rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
         bFound = .Execute
        Loop
      End With
      Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
    Next
End Sub
```

**Notes**

Since it's easier to control when having to loop numerous times, a `Range` object is used as the basic search object, rather than `Selection`. The found `Range` is only selected for the purpose of getting the entire line as these "Move" methods for lines only work on a Selection.

Before the loop can continue, the `Range` (or, if we were working with a selection, the selection) needs to be "collapsed" so that the code does not search and find the same instance of the search term, again. (This is also the reason for `Wrap = wdFindStop`).

Comment: Hello Cindy. Thanks so much for your help. It seems to work, but currently only prints one occurrence of the string searched. If string1 appears 3 times within document it seems is only printing the first one. How to do to print all occurrences?

Comment: Ah, I thought you might have enough experience to know how to put the code in a loop. I've changed it to a full solution...